# How to manipulate arrays with a custom function

Tags: javascript, arrays

So I have an array with each cell of the array containing a specific function.

```
var randomly = [
  function(a) { return a * a - a; },
  function(a) { return (a - 2) * (a - 1) * (a - 1); },
  function(a) { return a * a + a; },
  function(a) { return a % 3; }
];
```

I'm creating a function that that takes the input value (a) for the entire array and goes through each array cell individually, solves the function. However, the result of the function becomes the next function's input value. So the initial input value will only be good for the first function, and the next function's input falue will be the previous function's result.

To do this, I created a for loop...

```
var theFunction = function (input, queue){

  for (var i = 0; i < queue.length; i++){
    queue[i](input);


  }
```

So, here is where I'm stuck...

How can I call the specific array along with the input value? I used `queue[i](input);` but not sure if that's even valid. Any help on this would be much appreciated.

Comment: "_not sure if that's even valid_" Well did you try compiling/running your program to see what happens? If you did, explain what happened. If not, you should go do it.

Comment: Can you explain with a sample input and the expected output?

Answer (score 1):

You're close, but to "chain" the functions, you'll need to actually *store* the return values, so you can re-use them:

```
var theFunction = function (input, queue) {
  var result = input;

  for (var i = 0; i < queue.length; i++)
    result = queue[i](result);

  return result;
}
```

```js
var randomly = [
  function(a) { return a * a - a; },
  function(a) { return (a - 2) * (a - 1) * (a - 1); },
  function(a) { return a * a + a; },
  function(a) { return a % 3; }
];

var theFunction = function (input, queue) {
  var result = input;

  for (var i = 0; i < queue.length; i++)
    result = queue[i](result);

  return result;
}
  
  
console.log(theFunction(4, randomly));
```